# Display file contents within Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, forms, include

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong - I try to display forms from different files within my plugin. all is triggerd by my_shortcode where the via $atts the user choses which form to display.  This is working fine since $filepath has the correct path, but for some reason the form is never displayed in the html_output().
The file is also within the plugin structure. Please help! Thank you

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcodename', ' myshortcode ' );

function  myshortcode ($atts) {
    $output =  registration_form ($atts);
    return $output;
}

function  registration_form ($atts) {
    // which form shall be displayed
    $arr_assign =  shortcode_splitter ($atts);

    // possible error messages
     display_errors ();

    $output =  html_output ($arr_assign);
    return $output;
}

function  html_output ($arr_assign) {
    $filepath = $arr_assign['filepath'];
    $content = '';

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filepath;
        $content = ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        $content = "The file is not found <br>";
        $content .= $filepath;
    }

  esc_html("The file is not found" );
    echo $content;
    return $content;
}

function shortcode_splitter( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'type' => 'default',
    ), $atts );

    // Process the shortcode based on the 'type' attribute
    $type=  $a['type'];    

    if ( $type == 'form1' ) {
        // add additional info to form
     
     } else if ( $type == 'form2' ) {
        // add additional info to form
        
    } else if ( $type == 'form3' ) {
        // add additional info to form
           
    } else {
        // Process the default shortcode
        return 'Please select the proper shortcode';
    }
    
    $filepath = plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'forms/form-'.$type.'.php';
   
    $arr_assign['filepath'] = $filepath;

      return $arr_assign;

}
```

Comment: Allowing a user to execute an arbitrary file by passing its path to the shortcode seems extremely dangerous to me.

Comment: I suspect from the use of spaces in the shortcode name that your PHP error log is full of warnings and error messages that directly point out the problem, however you should not do this, it is extremely insecure and dangerous. This shortcode could be used to print out the contents of any file on your site, it's a massive security hole

Comment: You are totally right, I didn’t explain that properly: there are 3 forms to choose from and the user enters [shortcodename value=‘form1’] - no path is passed, the path is generated within the shortcode_splitter() based on the value entered (form1 or 2 or 3]

Comment: that doesn't protect you much, `html_output` is a fundamentally dangerous function, you should also be including `shortcode_splitter` in your question. If there are a limited number of known options you should also test against a list of those options to enforce only those can be used at an absolute minimum. Even if this isn't used to print out a file, you could pass arbitrary HTML in and it would print it as part of the `"This file is not found"` error message because there's no escaping ( `esc_html` can avoid this )

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - I didn't know how else to solve this. I added shortcode_splitter() - my goal is that depending on which shortcode parameter is passed the according form is displayed. The html for the forms is seperated into three files.